# Wordpress backend custom settings fields that can be added/generated by an admin user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In a nutshell what I'm trying to achieve is to let a user add some admin settings fields to a custom plugin via the backend and then populate them as required.

So the default settings page would have one Settings Field:

Location (with setting location_id) : (User enters location here and it gets stored in the database)

What I want to make happen is have a button that says "Add Another Location" which will automatically create a new settings field with an ID of location_id2. Adding a third would create a third field and the ID assigned sequentially.  (Ideally I would like to give the option to remove any of the fields but that is a secondary requirement.)

These fields would be saved in the database so I can call them later in the front end using `get_option('location_id')`;.

The code I have I currently have is for a single settings field

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mycustom_menu');

function mycustom_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page('mycustom Connect', 'mycustom Connect', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'mycustom_settings_page' , plugins_url('/images/icon1.png', __FILE__) );

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_mycustom_settings' );
}


function register_mycustom_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'mycustom-settings-group', 'location_id' );
}

function mycustom_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">

<h1><strong></strong>mycustom Settings</strong></strong></h1>

<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'mycustom-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'mycustom-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Location ID</th>
        <td><input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="location_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('location_id') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php }
```

Using this same code I can manually create many of these fields as I want but as the question states how can i let a backend user do this dynamically. I have searched through quite a few other questions and haven't been able to find anything that would even help me get started so any help would be greatly appreciated.

many thanks in advance!